# Output repeatable field based on user defined order

Tags: fix-my-code, module-display, form-fields-types

I have a very basic repeatable field where I am allowing the user to enter some field along with an input where they can enter the 'Display Order' [1,2,3,4,5]. But I am struggling with how I could apply any sorting function on the data that is stored for the repeatable field. A sample output is the following:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [order] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 3
        [2] => 2
    )
    [url] => Array
    (
        [0] => /first
        [1] => /third
        [2] => /second
    )
)
```

How would I go about so that when the module content is displayed in the front end; it would be based on the order defined by user [1,2,3] and not as it is currently [1,3,2].

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample function that can give you ordered list based on your order array.

```
public function getSortedArray($myObj, $ordering)
{
  // first build an array with keys as your order, values as data (url)
  $myArray = array();
  foreach($myObj->order as $i=>$order)
  {
    $myArray[$order] = $myObj->url[$i];
  }

  // now you can get the data as per the user requested order
  $return = array();
  foreach($ordering as $order)
  { 
    $return[] = $myArray[$order];
  }

  return $return;
}
```